# How to make sure classes that use trait have certain classes in them?

Tags: scala, traits

I want to create a trait, but I want all classes that will use this trait to have certain classes on them:

```
trait SomeHelper {
  def homeUrl(): String =
    s"$website.url"
}

class Foo(website: Website) extends SomeHelper {
  val hello = homeUrl + "/hello"
}
```

**How do I make a requirement on the trait user to have the website class?**

Answer (score 6):

In hope I've understood your requirement:

```
trait SomeHelper { self: Website =>
  def homeUrl(): String = s"$url"
}
```

Every implementor of `SomeHelper` must now `extend Website` or mixin `Website`.

If you don't want extension, traits are designed to contain unimplemented members as well as implemented ones you could simply:

```
 trait SomeHelper {

   def website: Website

   def homeUrl(): String = s"$website.url"
 }
```

On a side note, by convention methods with no side effects such as `homeUrl()` should not have `()`.

**Update**

If you have more than one trait, you can simply add more to the restriction:

```
trait Website {
  def url: String
}
trait Portal {
  // whatever you want here, I'm making stuff up
  def identity: String
}
trait SomeHelper { self: Website with Portal =>
  // when you mixin with a self type bound, you can call methods directly
  def homeUrl: String = s"$url:$identity"
}
```

Comment: what if I want more than 1 class like Website?

Comment: btw, how will the trait know that Website instance name is website?

Comment: @Blankman I've updated my example. As to your second question, don't confuse approaches, you either define a method which will have a name and that's how the trait "knows" or you use a self type bound and you just call the methods like in my updated example.